# ASP.Net StructureMap Injecting Previously Objects as Dependencies

Tags: asp.net, structuremap

(TLDR? Skip to the last couple of paragraphs for the questions...)

I have a classic ASP.Net site which was originally built around a data access layer consisting of static methods wrapping around ADO.Net. More recently, we've been introducing abstraction layers separated by interfaces which are glued together by StructureMap. However, even in this new, layered approach the repository layer still wraps around the old static ADO.Net classes (we weren't prepared to take on the task of implementing an ORM whilst simultaneously reorganising our application architecture).

This was working fine - until today. Whilst investigating some unexpected performance issues we've been having lately we noticed a couple of things about our data access classes:

1. Our SqlDataConnection instances aren't always being closed.
2. The connection objects are being stored in static variables.

Both of the above are bad practice and likely to be significantly contributing to our performance problems. The reason why the connections were being set in static variables was to share them across data access methods which is a good idea in theory - it's just a terrible implementation.

Our solution is to convert the static data access classes/methods into objects - with our core DataManager class being instantiated once at the beginning of a request and disposed once at the end (via a new PageBase class in the web layer - much of our code is not yet separated into layers). This means we have one instance of the data access class which gets used for the entire life cycle of the request and therefore only one connection.

The problem starts now when we get to the areas of the site using the newer layered architecture. With the older code, we could just pass a reference to the DataManager instance directly to the data access layer from the code behinds but this doesn't work when the layers are separated by interfaces and only StructureMap has knowledge of the different parts.

So, with all of the background out of the way here's the questions:

- Is it possible for StructureMap to create instances by passing previously instantiated objects as dependencies - within the context of a single ASP.Net Page lifecycle?
- If it is possible, how is this achieved? I haven't seen anything obvious in my searching and haven't had to do this in the past.
- If it is not possible, what might be an alternative solution to the problem I've described above?

NOTE: This may or may not be relevant: we're calling ObjectFactory.BuildUp( this ) in a special base page for those pages which have been converted to use the new Architecture - ASP.Net doesn't provide a good access point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this wasn't so hard in the end. Here's the code:

```
var instantiatedObject = new PropertyType();

ObjectFactory.Configure( x => 
    {
        x.For<IPropertyType>().Use( () => instantiatedObject );
        x.SetAllProperties( p => p.OfType<IPropertyType>() );
    }
);
```

We just put this in our PageBase class before the `ObjectFactory.BuildUp( this )` line. It feels slightly dirty to be putting IoC configuration in the main code like this - but it's classic ASP.Net and there aren't many alternatives. I guess we could have provided some abstraction.